# Inequality for convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

If $f$ is a convex function then, for all $a<b$ and $0\le c<b-a$,
$$f(a)+f(b)\ge f(a+c)+f(b-c).$$
What is the shortest proof for the inequality?

Comment: Any proof would have to copy with the counterexample $f(x)=x^2$, $a=0$, $b=98$, $c=99$, $d=100$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you for the comment. I have corrected the inequality.

Comment: $c$ is positive or can be also negative?

Comment: @Jihlbert Thank you! Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$ and $0<c< b-a$, suppose first to all that $a+c\leq b-c$ a property of convex functions in one variable says that
$$
\frac{f(b-c)-f(a)}{b-c-a}\leq\frac{f(b)-f(a+c)}{b-c-a}
$$
then
$$
f(b-c)+f(a+c)\leq f(b)+f(a)
$$

If $b-c<a+c$ then
$$
\frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{a+c-a}\leq\frac{f(b)-f(b-c)}{b-b+c}
$$

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be the simplest proof: for some $\beta,\ 0\le \beta\le 1$,
$$a+c=\beta a + (1-\beta)b,$$
$$b-c=(1-\beta)a + \beta b.$$
Then 
$$f(a)+f(b) \equiv (\beta f(a) + (1-\beta)f(b)) +
((1- \beta) f(a) + \beta f(b)) \ge
f(\beta a + (1-\beta)b) + f((1-\beta)a + \beta b)
\equiv f(a+c) + f(b-c).$$

Answer (score 0):

By given inequalities

$$(b,a) \succ (b-c, a+c) \;\;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\;\; (b,a) \succ (a+c, b-c)$$

holds. Using Karamata's Majorization Inequality gives the desired inequality.